# How to get rid of small thin worms?

Tags: pest-control

I have thousands of small thin worms stuck to my outdoor windows, walls, and pavers. They are all dead. They are all in one corner of my house. I have never seen them alive. We clean then off and then they just come back. There is a downpipe nearby, if that is relevant. I would like to get rid of the worms but do not want to kill any of the plants in the same area. The dead worms are mainly straight, few are curled up. The worms are a bit brown, red, see through with what looks like black food through the centre of the worm. They do not have legs. I live in Australia and the downpipe mentioned above is connected to guttering. I am not sure if the worms appear after rain, I have only seen one alive.
[image: WORMS]

Comment: Hi Stuart, as they say, a photo is worth a 1000 words. Please post a few. It will help users respond with a more definitive answer

Comment: Do the worms appear after its been raining? Or is it every day they're there? What part of the world are you in and can you add a photo or two of the affected area, with or without worms present please. And the downpipe you mention, is it connected to the guttering or a wastewater pipe?

Comment: @RohitGupta, I have added a photo to the original post.

Comment: @Bamboo. I live in Australia and the downpipe mentioned above is connected to guttering. I am not sure if the worms appear after rain, I have only seen one alive. I have added a photo to the original post.

Answer (score 0):

<take this advice with a bag of salt meaning don't trust it>

Eat eggs. Break up the shells. Pour them around the suspected worm sources. The shells shear soft tissue. <sub>Also provide nutrients to the garden.</sub>